# New to DNN.... inherited hacked site

Tags: dotnetnuke

I was just hired to maintain and redesign various site the company has running on an old version of DNN. The site has been hacked and someone uploaded some directories and web.config files that were redirecting users to stream suspicious streaming sites. Also, the attacker added some scripts that show Google Ads on all the blog articles. Needless to say its a mess.

Nevertheless, I was able to go in there, deleted a super admin account (that's how they got in I think) , delete a few directories that had over a thousand html files for streaming sites and also deleted the old FCK Editor.

I am completely new to DNN and need some help with the directory and structure to try and see if I can resolve this. So far, I cannot get rid of the Google Ads in the blog and for the life of me I cannot find where the blog articles live inside the root/directory. When I go in there and delete the ads through the DNN UI the ads come back in hours or a couple of days. The directories with the html files have not returned. Just the ads.

I know that we have to upgrade but if I remove the ads I will have more to to develop the new sites without feeling rushed because of the current issue.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Also check FTP accounts if they exist. They could be an entry point also. And not to be rude, but maybe you should look into hiring someone who knows DNN to clean a hacked site. This is not something a novice should do...

Answer (score 0):

That sounds awful, as obviously someone (ore something) still manipulates your site from the outside (or inside?). There are a lot of issues on old DNN Versions, and the only thing I can really recommend is to find an upgrade path to the newest version. I don't know how big your site is, maybe it is easier to set it up from scratch with a new version (if the site is not too big).

The directory structure does not help you finding any content as everything is stored in a database. To be more specific I would need more information about the DNN version and the extensions (and versions of the extensions) in use, but disclosing this here in the public could be a security risk for you. You could write me a PM here if you wish to get in contact.

To find people (maybe in your area) who can help you could give these web sites a try: https://dnncommunity.org (Resources > Forums) and https://dodnn.work/.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your site might have been impacted by a few different exploits, and most likely I would guess it is version 7.x or earlier and been upgraded from versions prior to that.

For the immediate need you are going to need to try and identify anything and everything that is out of the norm, this can be very daunting for those that are not familiar with the platform, but a few tips.

- Look in the DB for data in the Header or Footer field of the `TabModules` table
- Look for any rogue files that really should not be there, anything with an extension of (.php, .asp, etc.)
- Look for rogue files in directories outside of the /Portals/* folder that don't match a DNN Install.  (This takes a bit of personal experience.)
- Look at your default.aspx file it should NOT have a recent modified date.  If it does, compare it against the one that you get when you download the install package of that version of DNN

Now, once you have done this, be sure to do any mitigations that you can for known exploits.  Including:

- Delete /Install/Install.aspx
- Delete /Install/InstallWizard.aspx
- Disable any host account with a username of 'host' and create a new one if that was your only one

Feel free to email me directly as well if you need some help.